# SQL Azure - What type of encryption to use?

Tags: azure-sql-database

What type of encryption would you recommend me to do with SQL on Azure? Is there an existing encryption already defined within Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share an article, where cryptographic services and existing suppliers Azure explained. I hope it helps you.

It depends on your scenario, it is the case that it can better match your needs.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291586.aspx

Comment: Sorry, we can only accept contributions in English.

Answer (score 1):

Before selecting an encryption mechanism, it's important to evaluate the specific security requirements you need. Azure SQL provides some of the following options:

- TDE (Transparent Data Encryption): It's a mechanism that allows the encryption of all data in a specific database through activating a setting parameter. This means that the details of the encryption mechanism are not exposed to the developer, hence simplifying the process. More information can be found here: [Transparent Data Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx).
- Always Encrypted: This mechanism allows you to encrypt specific columns in tables. More details can be found here: [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx)

These options, and more, can be found at the following website: [SQL Server Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663.aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just submitted a translation for the original question. Can you enable it?